# I want to connect openshift mongodb database from my local client tools

Tags: node.js, mongodb, server, openshift, database

- I have my premium openshift account
- I have all types of access in openshift
- I have ssh key & user's credentials
- I have MongoVUE & Robomongo & others client tools to open mongodb database.
- when I try to open any local mongodb database then its working fine
- but I want to directly connect my mongodb database of openshift server to mongoVUE or any else
  so I can see which data is in my server database.
- I have tried so many times to connect locally but it can connect to openshift but can not connect with mongodb database so please provide some good & exact steps so I can connect it.

Comment: https://forums.openshift.com/connecting-to-mongodb-gear-using-your-local-mongo-client-and-rhc-port-forwarding

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got perfect tool for it to connect with mongodb with server database in which we can perform all kind of CRUD operations.
we can use Robomongo tool for it which doesn't require paid version to perform CRUD operation.
Robomongo is available here
http://robomongo.org/download.html
mongoVUE requires paid version.

I use Robomongo. Just do a 'rhc port-forward '

Then run Robomongo using the Mongodb credentials that OPENSHIFT gave you.

Steps.

rhc port-forward 
Wait a couple of seconds. You then should see something like this.

port forward image

Then run Robomongo. Add a connection and enter in your Openshift Mongodb credentials:

Answer (score 8):

I use mongovue also. Just do a 
       'rhc port-forward '

Then run mongovue using the Mongodb credentials that OPENSHIFT gave you.

Steps.

```
 rhc port-forward <app-name>
```

Wait a couple of seconds.  You then should see something like this.

[image: port forward image]

Then run Mongovue.  Add a connection and enter in your Openshift Mongodb credentials like this:

[image: Mongovue]

Save, Select your connection, and press connect.  It should work.

You should have been given you mongodb credentials when you added the mongodb cartridge.  You can also ssh into your app and do a "env" and see your  mongodb password and username.

Comment: can you please describe more precisely? what should I enter in server name, port, username & password? 'cause I have tried as you have said even though not able to connect database in MongoVUE.

Comment: thanks buddy now I am able to connect mongodb with MongoVUE but not  ablto do any CRUD operation from mongoVUE.

Comment: What exact operation is not working for you. Mongovue does have its limitations. Do you have the paid version? I have only done simple CRUD thru the gui and it works fine.

Comment: when I tried to remove, insert or update through this GUI version its going fail it throws authorization error. but i can retrieve all those data of server.

Comment: It works for me. You should give exact steps in your answer for any more help